# How to check dead links in a Gitlab CI job which builds a static site with MkDocs?

Tags: gitlab-ci, mkdocs, to-be-continuous

I use the [TBC MkDocs Gitlab-CI template](https://to-be-continuous.gitlab.io/doc/ref/mkdocs/) to build, then publish a static site which contains a lot of links to other sites.

So I should want to add in my CI job a check to verify:

1. If all my internal links (within the web site) are ok
2. if all my external links are alive.

Could you give me an advice to do that in a good way:

- what tools can I use ? for instance, I had a look to [linkchecker-markdown](https://github.com/scivision/linkchecker-markdown) for local links and [linkchecker](https://github.com/wummel/linkchecker) for external links
- how to implement the check in the CI job?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, `linkchecker-markdown` is a static markdown files linter and `linkchecker` is more like a website crawler testing all links.

So we could have a lint job for the sources in the `build` stage using `linkchecker-markdown` and `linkchecker` could be used in a job during the `acceptance` stage (see [ToBeContinuous generic pipeline stages](https://to-be-continuous.gitlab.io/doc/understand/#generic-pipeline-stages)). Note that the acceptance tests are usually performed against a staging environment before the production deployment.

If you think that one or the other (or both ^^) might be the solution you seek, feel free to [open issue(s) on the project](https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/mkdocs/-/issues) (merge requests are also very welcomed :) ).

Regards,
Yann