# mkdocs check link validity

Tags: markdown, mkdocs

I would like to know if we could verify that the links work with:

```
mkdocs build -s
```

for example I would like this line to return an error because it is invalid:

```
[bad link](https://zegfcv.zerty): bad link
```

or is there a tool to check that the http links work in my doc?

Comment: What makes that a "bad link"? Because it can't be resolved at build time?

Comment: yes, a link with 404 error
I would like to control the expired links automatically

Comment: MkDocs does not check external links (only internal ones). And asking for tool recommendations is off-topic here.

Comment: One might want to look at <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67924428/how-to-check-dead-links-in-a-gitlab-ci-job-which-builds-a-static-site-with-mkdoc>.